# Unable to install Jboss server on Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, server, jboss6.x

I am trying to install Jboss on Eclipse Luna. I have installed Jboss Tool, but when I try to define a server the Jboss option is not present. 
After clicking downloadable server adapter I selected Jboss AS WildFly & EAP server tools.
But it is unable to download the adapter with following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: JBoss AS, WildFly & EAP Server Tools 3.1.1.Final-v20160409-0826-B118 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.feature.feature.group 3.1.1.Final-v20160409-0826-B118)
  Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 4.4.1.20150109-0740 (epp.package.jee 4.4.1.20150109-0740)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Console 3.6.100.v20150822-1912 (org.eclipse.ui.console 3.6.100.v20150822-1912)
    Console 3.5.300.v20140424-1437 (org.eclipse.ui.console 3.5.300.v20140424-1437)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 4.4.1.20150109-0740 (epp.package.jee 4.4.1.20150109-0740)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group [4.4.1.20150109-0740]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EPP Java EE IDE Feature 4.4.1.20150109-0740 (org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.feature.feature.group 4.4.1.20150109-0740)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.4.0.v20140925-0400]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 4.4.0.v20140925-0400 (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 4.4.0.v20140925-0400)
    To: org.eclipse.ui.console [3.5.300.v20140424-1437]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss AS, WildFly & EAP Server Tools 3.1.1.Final-v20160409-0826-B118 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.feature.feature.group 3.1.1.Final-v20160409-0826-B118)
    To: org.jboss.tools.as.runtimes.integration [3.1.1.Final-v20160409-0826-B118]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss Server Adapter UI Framework 3.1.1.Final-v20160409-0826-B118 (org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.wtp.ui 3.1.1.Final-v20160409-0826-B118)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.ui.console 3.6.0
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JBoss AS, WildFly & EAP Server Tools - Runtimes Integration 3.1.1.Final-v20160409-0826-B118 (org.jboss.tools.as.runtimes.integration 3.1.1.Final-v20160409-0826-B118)
    To: bundle org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.wtp.ui 3.0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I uninstalled the Jboss Tool plug-in and installed it using the install new software (typing URL) instead of eclipse market place.

Though this is not the ideal answer but atleast I could begin working

Answer (score 0):

`org.eclipse.ui.console 3.6.100.v20150822-1912` is part of Eclipse Mars so this looks like this code requires Eclipse 4.5

Comment: So should i try to install earlier version of Jboss Tools?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue while plugin JBoss toll in 06-2019 Eclipse 4.12.0 version Eclipse this time using the Extracted JDK after using the Install JDK problem Solved